# Focus on next element by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

My purpose is moving focus to the next input element when the button fires `mouseup` event, here is the script:

```
var cleared = false;
$(document).ready(function(){

    //focus on first element
    var focused = null;
    $(".inp").focus(function () {
        focused = $(this);
    }).first().focus();

   //when mousedown, set value 4
    $("#btn").mousedown(function(e) {
        focused.val("4");  
    }).mouseup(function(e) {

        //when mouseup, change bg color
        focused.css("background-color","yellow");

        //and focus on next element
        if (focused && focused.length) {
            focused.next(".inp").focus();
        }       
    });
});
```

Here is my html element:

```
    <table>     
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td><input class="inp"/></td>
            <td><input class="inp"/></td>
            <td><input class="inp"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<button id="btn">4</button>Good
```

My problem is the focus never set the next, how can I solve this?

Comment: You need `focused.parent().next().find('.inp').focus();`

Comment: @DOCASAREL, wah, problem solved! Thank you! but I don't know the logic inside.

Comment: Since you have the reference to an input at `focused`, you need to access its parent (`<td>`). After that you can access its next element (the following `<td>`) and, inside it, find the `.inp` element, which is the one you want to focus on.

Comment: @zakariaAcharki did the full job! I was too slow. Happy that you liked it. You are always welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjyew3hL/)**

> **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** :Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

You have no 'immediately following sibling' with class `inp`, So you have to move up one time to the parent `td` and then move to the next td using `next()` funtion and then find inside this td the class `inp` and perform the focus.

**Just replace :**

```
focused.next(".inp").focus();
```

**By :**

```
focused.parent().next().find(".inp").focus();
```

**Full JS :**

```
var cleared = false;
$(document).ready(function(){

    //focus on first element
    var focused = null;
    $(".inp").focus(function () {
        focused = $(this);
    }).first().focus();

   //when mousedown, set value 4
    $("#btn").mousedown(function(e) {
        focused.val("4");  
    }).mouseup(function(e) {

        //when mouseup, change bg color
        focused.css("background-color","yellow");

        //and focus on next element
        if (focused && focused.length) {
            focused.parent().next().find(".inp").focus();
        }       
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this to focus on next element

```
 $(this).trigger("keydown", [9]);
```

replacing the following in your code

```
   if (focused && focused.length) {
        focused.next(".inp").focus();
    }
```